# Datadog’s Kafka integration DD_KAFKA_CLIENT_PROPAGATION_ENABLED - Magic v1 does not support record headers

Tags: apache-kafka, datadog

**Issue:**

> [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#3-0-kafka-consumer-1] WARN  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition

**Environment Setup:**

- *Kafka Version:* kafka_2.11-1.0.0
- *Producer Details:*
  Spring Boot Version: 2.5.0
  Kafka-Client: 2.7.1
- *Consumer Details:*
  Spring Boot Version: 1.5.19.RELEASE
  Kafka-Client: 0.10.0.1
- *DataDog*

**Scenario 1:**

We know Kafka older version does not support message header so we are not setting any message header in producer. So if we run application without datadog and when we publish message from producer, consumer is able to consume message.

**Conclusion:** With mixed kafka version and without datadog, consumer and producer are working fine.

**Scenario 2:**

After adding datadog, messages are not delivered to consumer and on consumer side we can see exception: [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#3-0-kafka-consumer-1] WARN  o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition

And when checked Kafka server logs, we can see Magic V1 error. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers

**Conclusion:** With datadog clearly which is adding message header, messages are not delivered to consumer.

**Solution** (but not working)
After going through datadog documentation I found solution to this problem which is: https://docs.datadoghq.com/fr/tracing/compatibility_requirements/java/ under the section: Network tracing offers the following features:

**Datadog Documentation:**
Kafka / Datadog integration works with Kafka version 0.11+, which supports Header API. This API is used to inject and extract the tracing context. If you are using a mixed-version environment, the Kafka broker may pass the most recent version of Kafka by mistake, and the plotter then attempts to inject headers that are not supported by the local producer. Additionally, older consumers are not able to consume the message due to the presence of the headers. To avoid these problems, if you use a mixed-version environment with Kafka versions prior to 0.11, disable the context of the spread with the variable following environment: `DD_KAFKA_CLIENT_PROPAGATION_ENABLED=false`.

So we added and run application and datadog agent using below command on windows (added flag `Ddd.kafka.client.propagation.enabled=false`):

```
java -javaagent:D:\Tools\Datadog\dd-java-agent-0.9.0.jar -Ddd.profiling.enabled=true -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=256 -Ddd.logs.injection=true -**Ddd.kafka.client.propagation.enabled=false** -Ddd.trace.sample.rate=1 -Ddd.service=my-app -Ddd.env=staging -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local-postgres <Application Jar File> -Ddd.version=1.0
```

**Expected behavior:** Datadog should not add header.

**Actual behavior:** Datadog is still adding header and so we are still getting Magic V1 error.

Kindly request to help those whoever faced similar issue and please guide in case if you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

We also experienced a similar issue in that we wanted to use the Datadog agent but did not want to use the Kafka integration. Instead, we wanted to have more control over span injection. Setting `DD_KAFKA_CLIENT_PROPAGATION_ENABLED=false` did not disable the Datadog logic; however, setting `DD_TRACE_CLASSES_EXCLUDED` environment variable did:

```
DD_TRACE_CLASSES_EXCLUDE="org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer,org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords"
```

With this environment variable set, the Datadog code should not be enabled and hence wont add anything to the Kafka headers.  I assume that the equivalent system property `dd.trace.classes.exclude` would have the same effect.

Related Datadog docs: https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup_overview/setup/java/?tab=containers
Related Datadog code:

- producer: https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-java/blob/069ffa9a637bd4bffce1bbb80e089e26a95adaeb/dd-java-agent/instrumentation/kafka-clients-0.11/src/main/java/datadog/trace/instrumentation/kafka_clients/KafkaProducerInstrumentation.java#L38
- consumer: https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-java/blob/069ffa9a637bd4bffce1bbb80e089e26a95adaeb/dd-java-agent/instrumentation/kafka-clients-0.11/src/main/java/datadog/trace/instrumentation/kafka_clients/KafkaConsumerInstrumentation.java#L30